# How to find matrix error in matlab after using ode45?

Tags: matlab

Currently, I have used ode45 with a function that outputs a matrix (C) that 3945x9. These are supposed to be 3x3 matrices, so I did C = reshape(C.',3,3,[]). Now, I have a 3x3x3945 matrix. What I want to do is find the error of each 3x3 matrix. This is done using C*C.' - eye(3). However, I do not know how to do this with all my data now. It will work for something like C(:,:,1)*C(:,:,1).' - eye(3). However, not C(:,:,:)*C(:,:,:) - eye(3).

Answer (score 0):

Use the nD matrix multiply routine pagemtimes. E.g.,

```
pagemtimes(C,'none',C,'transpose') - eye(3)
```